# TSQL select varchar as windows1252 instead of utf8

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, utf-8, windows-1252

How to query Sql server getting strings as windows1252 charset instead of the table/connection default utf8?

Comment: The database is in `windows1252` but you want to get the data in `utf8`? - Am I getting the question right?

Comment: The opposite, I generally use this db for web-application that uses utf8 chars, now I want a win1252 chars for a particular data export.